# how to change the font type in GUI in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used GUI to display this text in unity :

```
GUI.Label(Rect(430,320,500,500),"Win");


GUI.Label(Rect(400,470,500,500),"Your scores :" +player_script.points);
```

I want to make the text like this :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify your gui code like this

```
GUI.Label(Rect(430,320,500,500),"<color=green><size=100>Win</size></color>");


GUI.Label(Rect(400,470,500,500),"<color=green><size=35>Your scores : </size></color>"+"<color=black><size=35>"+player_script.points+"</size></color>");
```

also if you want to change the font type then you can try this rich tag and let me know if it has worked

```
<font face="verdana">....</font>
```